# Regular expression for comment and string in flex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I have to recognize both single line and multi-line comment and string using flex.

Sample input for comment:

```
//this is a single line comment
//this is a single \ line comment too
//but this\
is a multi line comment
/* multi line \\n\
comment */
```

Output should correctly recognize the comments.

Sample Input for string:

```
"abc"
"abc \\\\ \t \\t def\" "
"abc \\\\ \t \\t def\" \"
"abc
""
"foo \
bar"
"foo \\
bar"
```

Output should be:

```
Line No. 1: Token <STRING> Lexeme "abc" found

Line No. 2: Token <STRING> Lexeme "abc \\\\ \t \\t def\" " found

Error at line 3. Missing terminating character "abc \\\\ \t \\t def\" 
\"

Error at line 4. Missing terminating character "abc

Line No. 5: Token <STRING> Lexeme "" found

Line No. 6: Token <STRING> Lexeme "for \
bar" found

Line No. 8. Token <STRING> Lexeme "for \\
bar" found
```

I also have to handle ill formed/unterminated comment or string, as it is evident from the sample example.

How can I write regex to handle this?

My approach (so far):

```
NEWLINE \r?\n

STRING \"([^"\n]|\\(.|{NEWLINE}))*\"
```

This is for the string. I don't know if it's correct. I don't have any approach for comment. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need to use start states to handle multi-line constructions. You'll never get it to work correctly without them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think writing a single RE is a good idea (or even possible) to cover all possible cases. How about trying something like this:

For matching strings

- multiline string `"(([^\n]|\\\n)*)(?<!\\)"`
- badly formated string `"(.*)((?<=\\)"|[^"\\])$`

(using lookarounds to eliminate or include escaped quotes, you can read more [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))

For matching comments

- single and multiline comment  with // `^\/\/((\\\n)|[^\n])*`
- multiline comment with /* */ `^\/\*(.*)\*\/` (this one must run with "dot matching new line" option enabled)

Hope this helps.